# How to make sure a controller is annotated by a specific annotation in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, annotations, netflix-feign

`@FeignClient` and `@RequestMapping` could not be added to the same interface. Now I want to check whether the two annotations were used an the same time to give some error messages.

**Question:**

Is there a something like `isAnnotatedBy(Annotation annotation)` method supported in spring? If not, how could I achieve my goal here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you are having trouble related to this issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/466.

The spring applicationContext offers utility methods for looking up beans with certain annotations present.

The solution could involve bootstrapping the start of the applicationContext and searching for your overlapping annotations there.

For this to work your need to register an ApplicationListener which searches all of your @RequestMapping beans which are further annotated with @FeignClient.

The implementation might look like :

```
@Component
public class ContextStartupListener
        implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Autowired    
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event){
    for(String beanName : applicationContext.getBeanNamesForAnnotation(RequestMapping.class)) {
           if(applicationContext.findAnnotationOnBean(beanName, FeignClient.class)!=null){
                throw new AnnotationConfigurationException("Cannot have both @RequestMapping and @FeignClient on "+beanName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reminder that I don't need to go to the trouble of using reflection and packages and Guava's @Beta classloader helpers to find Spring-annotated beans!

Answer (score 0):

There is already supported method named `isAnnotationPresent`:

```
boolean isAnnotationPresent(Class<? extends Annotation> annotationClass)
Returns true if an annotation for the specified type is present on this element, else false. This method is designed primarily for convenient access to marker annotations.
Parameters:
annotationClass - the Class object corresponding to the annotation type
Returns:
true if an annotation for the specified annotation type is present on this element, else false
Throws:
NullPointerException - if the given annotation class is null
Since:
1.5
```